# Spring NamedParameterJdbcTemplate delete with IN clause

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

When I try to execute a delete, with `items` set to a `List<String>`, `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` seems to be not setting values for all placeholders of generated statement.

```
public class DBTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        basicDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?rewriteBatchedStatements=true");
        basicDataSource.setUsername("root");
        basicDataSource.setPassword("qwedsa");

        NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(new JdbcTemplate(basicDataSource));

        ImmutableMap<String, ?> param = ImmutableMap.of("items", newArrayList("a", "b", "c"), "user_id", 1);
        Map<String, ?>[] params = new Map[]{param};
        template.batchUpdate("delete from sample where col1 in (:items) and user_id = :user_id", params);
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
bad SQL grammar [delete from sample where col1 in (?, ?, ?) and user_id = ?];
nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 3
```

Doesn't `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` expand lists for delete statements?

Comment: I tried your code and it worked just fine for me. What version of Spring are you using?

Comment: @geoand 4.0.5.RELEASE

Comment: I tried it on `3.2.8.RELEASE` and worked just fine. Can you post the whole method you are using?

Comment: Please try changing :  `new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(new JdbcTemplate(basicDataSource))` to `new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(basicDataSource)`

Comment: That doesn't change anything. I've update the question with the source code.

Comment: Check out my answer below

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        basicDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?rewriteBatchedStatements=true");
        basicDataSource.setUsername("root");
        basicDataSource.setPassword("qwedsa");

        NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(basicDataSource);

        ImmutableMap<String, ?> param = ImmutableMap.of("items", newArrayList("a", "b", "c"), "user_id", 1);
        template.update("delete from sample where col1 in (:items) and user_id = :user_id", param);
    }
```

which works just fine

Comment: In the actual application, I have a batch with such params.

Comment: So you actually need the `batchUpdate` method?